# python for loop, compact to a one-liner

Tags: python-2.7

I was wondering, if anyone have an idea. Is it possible to compress the following code into a one-liner?

```
X = ("10.0.0."+str(x) for x in range(100))
for IP in X:
    print IP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print "\n".join("10.0.0."+str(x) for x in range(100))
```